# How to synchronize offline files after each save?

Tags: smb, offline-files

I have an SMB share mounted in Windows 11. I enabled offline files for specific files. Now I noticed that I can press the synchronize button in the Windows 11 Sync Center or the context menu to synchronize the files from the SMB share to my Windows 11 offline file directory, but this doesn't happen automatically. I want an automatic synchronization on every save/write of the specific files or periodically, e.g., daily, to prevent forgetting it for these important offline files.

How can I achieve this? I found no documentation about the automatization of this in Microsoft's help documentation.